# Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

My client is using SQL Server 2014 Express edition on Windows Server 2012 (8 gb Ram).

Their database size is 500 mb now, with 35 users.

My question is: should they purchase SQL Server CAL licenses? Or are those not needed?

Comment: SQL Server **Express** is absolutely and utterly free to use - for whatever purpose. Absolutely no need to purchase licenses. The database size can grow up to 10 GB (per database). As long as that's enough - just use it and be happy !

Comment: Thanks Marc_s for reply.... but my question is they need to buy any CAL lic. and server ram decrease to 1 GB

Comment: As I already said: **NO**, they don't need to buy any licenses of any kind. And yes - SQL Server **Express** is limited to using 1 GB of RAM on the server - but you don't have to physically reduce the RAM to 1 GB - SQL Server Express just won't use more than 1 GB